# PCRE: pattern for unicode characters (hex code)

Tags: php, design-patterns, pcre

What is the PCRE pattern, in PHP, for characters with hex code from `\x00` to `\xFF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To match a specific Unicode code point, use **\uFFFF** where FFFF is the
>   hexadecimal number of the code point you want to match. **You must
>   always specify 4 hexadecimal digits**. E.g. \u00E0 matches "à", but only
>   when encoded as a single code point U+00E0.

Source: [Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)